# Set Initial language for LocalizedStrings React native localization

Tags: react-native

How to set initial language?
Currently, when i click change language, the language will save to async storage and when i open the app, it will read the language and set to localization
here are codes


**translate.js**

```
const initLocale = () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('@Locale').then(local => {
        console.log('logged by phuognn local: ', local);
        if (local)
            strings.setLanguage(local)
    })
}
export { strings, changeLaguage, initLocale }
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {

    NavServices.setNavigator(this.navRef);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationContainer ref={ref => this.navRef = ref}>
          <MainStack />
        </NavigationContainer>
      </Provider>
    )
  };
};
```

But its not work as expected.

In the login screen, language still in english but after login, navigate to home screen its goes to vietnamese

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because, When your component mounted, AsyncStorage not get data from storage.When set this code ```strings.setLanguage(local)``, home screen component is not mounted. For this reason, login screen is english and home screen is vietnamese.

Solution:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      localeLoaded: false,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    NavServices.setNavigator(this.navRef);
    AsyncStorage.getItem("@Locale").then((local) => {
      console.log("logged by phuognn local: ", local);
      if (local) strings.setLanguage(local);
      this.setState({ localeLoaded: true });
    });
  }
  render() {
    if (!this.state.localeLoaded) {
      return <ActivityIndicator />;
    }
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationContainer ref={(ref) => (this.navRef = ref)}>
          <MainStack />
        </NavigationContainer>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i'm also think the login screen mounted before the local strings get from storage, but if i return the Activity, it will always take times to check even when we not changing the language. is that affect UX so much?

Comment: When language is changed, reload the app. I don't like this. I am using context for this. When I change language, all text changes without loading.
You can use this library  `context-multi-language`. I developed it. it is useful and easy.